# LINQ to Entities extensions; multiple subqueries, joins and case statements

Tags: c#, linq

I have googled thoroughly for examples to my latest LINQ endeavor ("Hi, I'm new to LINQ"). I'll spare you the list of pages I've visited.

Here is sample SQL of what I would like to achieve:

```
use myDB;
go

declare @requestedDay datetime = convert(datetime, (convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)), 101)
declare @type1 int = 20

;with currentQuery as ( select
case when z.someID = @type1 and bet.someValue is null then 1
    else 0 end as count1,
case when z.someID = @type1 and bet.someValue = alef.otherID then 1
    else 0 end as count2,
from dbo.Work as dalet
    left join dbo.Workers as z on alef.workerAssignedID = z.ID
    left join dbo.Contracts as alef on alef.workOrderID = gimel.ID
    left join dbo.Subcontracts as bet on alef.WorkOrderID = alef.WorkOrderID 
                  and alef.WorkerAssignedID = dalet.WorkerID 
where convert(varchar(10),alef.dateTimeofWork,101) = @requestedDay),
futureQuery as ( select
case when gimel.text_EN like '%blah%' and bet.someValue is null then 1
    else 0 end as count3,
case z.someID = @type1 and bet.someValue = alef.otherID then 1
    else 0 end as count4,
from dbo.Work as dalet
    left join dbo.Workers as z on dalet.workerAssignedID = z.ID
    left join dbo.Contracts as alef on dalet.workOrderID = alef.ID
    left join dbo.Subcontracts as bet on dalet.WorkOrderID = bet.WorkOrderID and wa.WorkerAssignedID = wr.WorkerID 
    left join dbo.Lookups as gimel on dalet.skillID = gimel.ID
where convert(datetime,(convert(varchar(10),alef.dateTimeofWork,101)),101) > @requestedDay)
select sum(count1) as prop1name, sum(count2) as prop2name, 
sum(count3) as prop3name, sum(count4) as prop4name
from currentQuery, futureQuery
```

This is, of course, a shortened version of a much larger query. It contains just the basics of what I need. The names may be confusing but I was looking for something unique. They also match their LINQ cousins below.

...that said, here is where I am stuck: ("What I have tried so far:") I've included some comments that describe problems I am trying to think through.

```
//snip injection stuff above
    public IQueryable<DailyCasaLatinaReport> DailyCasaLatina(DateTime dateRequested)
    {
        IQueryable<DailyCasaLatinaReport> query;

        var daletQ = waRepo.GetAllQ();
        var zQ = zRepo.GetAllQ();
        var alefQ = alefRepo.GetAllQ();
        var betQ = betRepo.GetAllQ();
        var gimelQ = gimelRepo.GetAllQ();

        int type1 = 20;
        int type2 = 21;

        query = daletQ
                   .GroupJoin(gimelQ, dalet => dalet.skillID, look => look.ID,
                                 (dalet, look) => new
                                 {
                                     dalet,
                                     enSkillText = look.FirstOrDefault().text_EN
                                 }) //currently envisioning a left outer join of
                                    //all .skillID, with English text available
                                    //for column and condition matches from the
                                    //next three joins.
                   .GroupJoin(betQ, gimel => gimel.dalet.workOrderID, wr => wr.WorkOrderID,
                                  (gimel, wr) => new
                                  {
                                      gimel,
                                      reqWorkerID = wr.FirstOrDefault().WorkerID,
                                      reqOrderID = wr.FirstOrDefault().WorkOrderID
                                  }) //now envisioning a join on the original table
                                     //where any match in workerID is joined. THIS
                                     //IS A PROBLEM, I actually need to join on two
                                     //conditions to avoid duplicates.
                   .GroupJoin(alefQ, bet => bet.gimel.dalet.workOrderID, wo => wo.ID,
                                  (bet, wo) => new
                                  {
                                      bet,
                                      timeOfWork = wo.FirstOrDefault().dateTimeofWork
                                  }) //now envisioning yet another join where the
                                     //dateTimeofWork property from woQ is stamped
                                     //onto all matches of woQ's ID column. since
                                     //woQ.ID is the common point of reference for
                                     //like, everything, there should be no nulls.
                   .GroupJoin(zQ, alef => alef.bet.gimel.dalet.workerAssignedID, w => w.ID,
                                 (alef, w) => new
                                {
                                    alef,
                                    listDWC = alef.bet.someValue == 0 ? (w.FirstOrDefault().someID == type1 ? 1 : 0) : 0,
                                    propioDWC = alef.bet.someValue == alef.bet.gimel.dalet.workerAssignedID ? 
                                                    (w.FirstOrDefault().someID == type1 ? 1 : 0) : 0,

                                })  
                                    // here I'm stuck because there's no way to do 
                                    //the future conditions, i.e., what would be my 
                                    //second subquery
                   .Where(x => x.alef.timeOfWork == dateRequested)
                   .GroupBy(y => y.alef.bet.gimel.dalet.ID)
                   .Select(group => new dailyReport
                                {
                                    count1 = group.Sum(z => z.listDWC),
                                    count2 = group.Sum(z => z.propioDWC),
                                    count3 = //???
                                    count4 = //???
                                });

        return query;
    }
//snip class definition below
```

So, sorry for the long question (though I've seen longer), but any ideas about how to squeeze my second subquery in here would be helpful. I don't know LINQ that well and honestly don't know if I can put a separate .Where clause and/or second .Select clause. One thing to note is that dailyReport is a defined class and must have (in our example) count1 thru count4 defined.

Appreciate any help,

Chaim

Comment: While there are no doubt folks that can tell you how to put it all in one query, I find that breaking it into smaller chunks is much more readable.  Remember, you dont lose anything by doing this.  LINQ is not executed until you do something like `ToList()`, or try to look at the data.  IOW, Create a var of one bit and use it in the next query.

Comment: If you go back to the business requirements that forced you to create that monster of a sql statement because sql is set based, you could recreate the same results in linq much more simply and have them follow the business rules in a more manageable fashion.

Comment: Trying that. Will post an edit when I have more manageable bits.

Comment: Excellent, I should add, that while you will easily gain more manageable code, your query plan may suffer.  It may force you to optimize on a db level in different ways that you would with your monster sql query.  Fingers crossed for you. :)

Comment: So I would edit this, but I think it's become a new question. Breaking it up seems the right direction to go, though, so kudos to you, even if only in comments!

Comment: No worries, if you dont mind I'll add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments it was determined that breaking up this monster sql query would be more beneficial to the maintainability of his code and a new question will be created if needed.